# Safety factor for pressurized container at 10 ATM

Tags: pressure, measurements, pressure-vessel

There is no secondary containment to hold any potential shrapnel. How would this change the safety factor that is standard at 2.5? The consequences of this container exploding would be quite extreme as it is under high pressure.

Comment: The internal pressure doesn't really matter. What is important is the stress in the container. For example Scuba diving air tanks don't have any secondary containment for pressures of 200 ATM - because that is the pressure they are designed for.

Comment: 10ATM isn't that high when you consider that a typical operating pressure of a common espresso machine is 10-15 ATM.  The important thing to consider is that the design of the vessel is correct. That's why there are design codes engineers follow for things like pressure vessels, boilers and the like.

Comment: Also, you want a material that will exhibit ductile failure rather than brittle.